# How to Concat char according to string length in SQL

Tags: sql

How to Append char according to its char length,
I need to display another column as  Updated_Ref_No its length should be 8 and  it has refNo+ #
If ref No has 4 chars should append 4 '#', if it has 7 char should append 1 '#'

----  owner table -----

| Owner_Name | Ref_No |
| --- | --- |
| Ajmal | 48534 |
| Jeewan | 42 |
| Samal | 5534 |
| Jeewan | 42 |

Output Should be

| Owner_Name | Ref_No | Updated_Ref_No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ajmal | 48534 | 48534### |
| Jeewan | 42 | 42###### |
| Samal | 5534 | 5534#### |
| Jeewan | 42 | 42###### |

What is the best SQL Query to get this output

Comment: Mysql has nothing to do with plsql. Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas can you give a solution?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Oracle (as one of comments mentions PL/SQL which is procedural extension to Oracle's SQL), you'd use `RPAD` function which right-pads string (`ref_no`) to certain length (`8`) with some character (`#`):

```
SQL> select owner_name,
  2         ref_no,
  3         rpad(ref_no, 8, '#') updated_ref_no
  4  from owner;

OWNER_NAME     REF_NO UPDATED_REF_NO
---------- ---------- --------------------------------
Ajmal           48534 48534###
Jeewan             42 42######
Samal            5543 5543####
Jeewan             42 42######

SQL>
```

Comment: This is the exact answer that I was looking for really appreciate @Littlefoot

Answer (score 1):

In MySql you can use `repeat`

```
select concat(Ref_No,repeat('#',8-length(Ref_No))) as Updated_Ref_No
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

As ref_no is used as string here so '+' sign is used for concatanation. Otherwise concat keyword is used.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT owner_name
     , ref_no
     , LEFT(ref_no + '########', 8) updated_ref_no
FROM owner;
```

Please check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7eab1145e5d330c54ded3a77575b364

Alternate way by using replicate function in SQL SERVER

```
SELECT owner_name
     , ref_no
     , LEFT((ref_no + REPLICATE('#', 8)), 8) updated_ref_no
FROM owner;
```

Please check the url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c19b825ef453afc91dd7236776dd6e1

Comment: Thanks @Rahul really appreciate